# How to root ZTE Maven?

Tags: rooting

I have a ZTE Maven phone, and I want to root it.

There doesn't seem to be any applications that can successfully do that.

How to root ZTE Maven? Just in case it's relevant, the model number is Z812.

Comment: Might help if you at least told us the model... The generic method is unlock bootloader, flash custom recovery, flash SuperSU... beyond that, one-click root methods should be avoided unless they are specifically designed for your device, using an incorrect root method could brick your device.

Comment: Hmm... I found a thread on XDA (the mostly likely place to find a root method), but all I found was a small group of people who have been trying since August 2015 and been unsuccessful. http://forum.xda-developers.com/zte-z7/help/xte-maven-z812-t3155895 This is likely due to the new security methods in Lollipop and continued into Marshmallow where it is virtually impossible to root unless you can unlock the bootloader of the device, which doesn't seem possible on this device. (I just gave the thread a quick read, so take it with a grain of salt)